# Does Lightning Lure pull a creature toward you regardless of other circumstances?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, forced-movement

*Lightning Lure* pulls a creature toward you:

> You create a lash of lightning energy that strikes at one creature of
>   your choice that you can see within range. The target must succeed on
>   a Strength saving throw or be pulled up to 10 feet in a straight line
>   toward you and then take 1d8 lightning damage if it is within 5 feet
>   of you. (*Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide*, p. 143)

Does *lightning lure* pull a creature toward you regardless of other circumstances?

For instance, if you're chained by the wrist to an immovable object, does *lightning lure* pull until something gives, perhaps your wrist?

My own thinking is that the RAW does not address anything like this, so it is up to the GM's judgement.

I would like to know if this is a reasonable interpretation or alternatively, what might be a reasonable ruling.

Comment: Note: The wording of the spell was updated when it was reprinted in *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*, and SCAG was errataed accordingly, but it doesn't change the answer to the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Does lightning lure pull a creature toward you regardless of other circumstances?*

No. The key words here "up to 10 feet" If something prevents it from being pulled, that would pull it 0 feet, which is included in up to 10 feet.  Likewise, if there is suddenly a wall 5 feet away from the creature between you and it, it would stop when it hits the stone wall. They still roll the save, and on fail they move 0 feet but if they are within the distance, they still take the damage. That is my interpretation of the RAW.

I'd argue that grappled is muddier and that would require a DM call.  The question is what is stronger the grappler's hold on the target or the spell.  I'd personally rule that when the target makes a failed save, a contested roll be made between the spell caster's spell attack modifier and the grapperler's strength roll.

Comment: For the grappled condition, see [Does forced movement on a creature suffering the Grappled condition break the grapple?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/78065/26074)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a DM call.

Personally, I would rule that a creature who is securely restrained *cannot* fail the Strength saving throw. Alternatively if it was grappled by another creature, they would *both* need to fail the saving throw.