# What are the effects of a Warlock's Repelling Blast when pushing the target?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, forced-movement

If a Warlock's repelling blast evocation hits a target, what are the effects if:

1. There is a wall 5' behind the target?
2. There is another creature directly behind the target?
3. There is another creature 10' behind the target where they would normally land?
4. There is a pit directly behind the target (do they get any save)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The creature will be pushed into the wall, and its movement is stopped. Depending on the construction of the wall, it could be determined that subsequent attacks with Eldritch Blast will push the creature through the wall.
2. Is the creature friendly or hostile? Has the creature used their reaction yet? At the start, a medium or smaller creature is able to sidestep the pushed creature as it travels through the space. A larger creature would fully occupy the square, possibly arresting the movement. At a higher complexity level, it could be determined that the creature uses their reaction to hinder or help the pushed creature, whether by catching them and arresting their movement or tripping them as they pass through their square. Use the appropriate ability check to do so. Success is good, mediocrity is meh, and failure results in a negative result (knocked prone or tripped up).
3. If the space at 10' is occupied, then let the creature fall out to a side, preferably without a negative result. Choose the land, vice the pit, etc. Beyond this complexity, choose the funnier outcome.
4. RAW doesn't provide a save; thematically, a dexterity or strength save could be given, letting them catch the edge. Dependent on the depth of the pit, a similar save could be supported at the bottom.

Answer (score 8):

Repelling blast say "may" and "up to" if there something that would stop them from moving the full distance, it does. That means wall or character in the way would prevent movement. They will move until either they hit something they cannot pass, you can't push any more, or you chose to stop pushing.  Grapple, RAW, does not stop the movement.  A pit, RAW, doesn't get a save; many DMs may allow one to see if you can "catch the edge" if you stop adjacent to the edge, but that is houserule/DM call.

Related: [Does Lightning Lure pull a creature toward you regardless of other circumstances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79021)

Comment: Do you want to address the point of being able to "move through a friendly creature" such that if the repel pushes an enemy of the warlock through one if its allies it would not necessarily be obstructed by an ally behind them?

Comment: Or give the friendly creature the opportunity to use their reaction to catch the ally, with the risk of being knocked down.

Answer (score 0):

Although RAW does not allow for saves or what happens if you hit a wall or another character, one option (that one of my DMs used) was that a saving throw (Strength)  would be used on every casting of repelling blast.  On failing the save, to hit a wall would add a 1d4 of damage (depending on whether it is a large character or not).

Additionally the DM halved the backwards movement to the character being hit, and gave backwards movement instead to the one who was 5' behind the target when there was a creature behind it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to get a feel for how a Q&A site works differently from a forum.  If you could describe or explain  how your DM's ruling influenced play (beyond the mechanical details) it could improve the applicability of your answer to similar situations at another table.