# Can Lightning Lure pull a creature through a friendly or enemy creature's space?

Tags: dnd-5e

An enemy creature is 10 feet away from the caster. Right next to the creature is another enemy or friendly creature. Can Lighting Lure pull the target creature through the other creature's space, and into the empty space next to the caster?

Comment: Related: "[Can a Druid pull a target through other creatures with Thorn Whip?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164987)" and perhaps: "[Does Lightning Lure pull a creature toward you regardless of other circumstances?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79021)"