# Is Lightning Lure like a tractor beam?

Tags: dnd-5e, cantrips, forced-movement, falling

*[Lightning Lure](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/lightning-lure)* says (among other things):

> The target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pulled up to 10 feet in a straight line toward you...

"In a straight line" here leads to an interesting question.  If there's a hole in the floor between you and the pulled creature, will the creature be pulled over it as though Lightning Lure had created a tiny Star Trek tractor beam?  That *is* a straight line, after all.  Or will the creature fall through?

One situation when this might be relevant is if you want to immediately pull an ally (who doesn't mind a little friendly fire) over a small gap instead of waiting for them to jump on their turn.

Comment: A small aside, since Lightning Lure has a range of 15 feet, pulls "up to" 10 feet, and only deals damage if the target lands within 5 feet, you could in theory pull someone across a gap of just under 10 feet without dealing any friendly fire damage.

Comment: @zach  True, although there isn't really space for that if you're playing on a 5-foot-grid (15 = ally starting spot, 10 = hole, 5 = ending spot = damage spot, 0 = caster).

Answer (score 30):

### Ask your DM

This is not explicitly specified in the description of the spell, or the rules. It will depend on how your DM interpret the spell description if you do a 10-ft pull and a hole is between the caster and target.

**What I would do:** resolve the spell as up to 10-ft pull, regardless of terrain. If after resolving the target ends up on a tile with a hole, it will fall.

This interpretation is more based on simplicity and intuitive interpretation by my group.

---

If your player wants to tactically pull a target into the hole, instead of pulling it 10-ft, just pull it 5-ft, then it will fall into the hole and we don't need to question what would happen.

Comment: +1. Allowing _lightning lure_ to pull a target such that it clears a pit under the circumstances you suggest is more likely to reward both creative play and tactical thinking.

Comment: "regardless of terrain" That would apply to the opposite of holes? Small hills or pillars or what have you? "I cast pull on you and pull you through the wall... and laugh as you then fall into a hole"

Comment: @WernerCD 'gotchas' are usually not pleasant for the players. If it's something the players didn't expect, I offer a retcon, or allow what *they* expect to happen, if it's not unreasonable. I believe they won't try to pull something *into* a wall or object. At most, they would try to ask for extra damage as they slam the enemy into a wall.

Comment: @wernerCD  "pull you through the wall" ... line of sight to make the spell possible?

Comment: @PatrickArtner *Lightning lure*: "You create a lash of lightning energy that strikes at one creature of your choice that you can see within 15 feet of you." ... "I can see you through a window in a brick wall... I cast lure on you and pull you too me" Or I can see you through metal bars. Or a crack in stone. Straight line doesn't mean clear line - just like there could be a hole... there could be plenty of options for seeing you with obstacles in the way.

Comment: @WernerCD Just a gentle request to not link to pirate copies of copyrighted material.

Comment: @Someone_Evil sorry... just a top result after a google search of simple information. Didn't expect issues or any sort of a kurfuffle.

Answer (score 7):

### Probably not

The spell description says only that target is being "pulled", without further clarifications of the process.

However, Lightning Lure asks for a Strength saving throw. This implies the target can use its pure muscular strength to resist being pulled, so it probably stays on foot during the spell effect. If the target was afloat during the spell, this wasn't the case.

You can treat the spell effect as a lightning lasso which disappears right after being used. This also goes well with the description:

> You create **a lash of lightning energy** that strikes at one creature

Comment: I also picture it as a sort of lasso/whip. It's basically identical to *Thorn Whip* except for the range and damage type.

Comment: adding what happens, whether they fall through or not, will improve this answer

Answer (score 4):

## Yes you can pull the creature

**Lightning Lure** says:

> The target must succeed on a Strength saving throw or be pulled up to 10 feet in a straight line toward you

As opposed to this spell, we can consider the 1st level spell **Dissonant Whispers**. The spell's description says the following:

> The creature doesn’t move into obviously dangerous ground, such as a fire or a pit. On a successful save, the target takes half as much damage and doesn’t have to move away.

We can also consider the next nuance, the usual knockback, in which we simply roll the **Athletics check** - it simply knocks back 5 feet in a straight line. Nothing prevents us from pushing the creature into the hole.

Next, consider the **Eldritch Blast** cantrip and one of the upgrades for it, **Repelling Blast**.

> When you hit a creature with Eldritch Blast, you can push the creature up to 10 feet away from you in a straight line.

The creature should also fly 10 feet in a straight line away from you.

There is also the **Thunderwave** spell.

> On a failed save, a creature takes 2d8 thunder damage and is pushed 10 feet away from you.

Now let's draw a conclusion based on our introduction to spells. If you pull the creature, this is a different version of pushed - this means the following, if one end of the pit, like the other, is at the same height and the distance allows, then yes, you can do it. Because the description of the spell does not prevent you from doing that. There is no indication of safe areas or that it breaks. The only problem with these spells is the height difference and distance.

Comment: typically as soon as someone goes over a cliff or pit they fall though

Comment: Your logic here is somewhat difficult for me to follow.  Please consider editing it for clarity.

Answer (score -1):

### Usually No

Spells do what they say they do; *lightning lure* does not say that it grants any sort of flying or hovering ability to the targeted creature.  It is a lash of lightning energy, so it is physically pulling them(the strength save). It is not a tractor beam so much as a whip.

#### If using basic falling rules it is up to interpretation...

... but most GMs will say that falls are instantaneous

There are no rules in the core books that mention when falling occurs.
Common sense says it happens as soon as you step off the edge of a cliff (or are pushed or pulled off), but some GMs will allow you to not fall until your turn.  In the case where you are letting people not fall until their turn, you can pull them over the cliff - otherwise you can't.

#### If following Xanthar's optional falling rule 500ft/round

According to *Xanathar's Guide* falling is instantaneous. That means (mechanically) that even reactions can't save you except for *feather fall* as it specifically says that it can. If you are using *Xanathar's* then it is RAW that falling happens instantaneously and therefore as soon as a 'push or pull' pulls them into the pit space they fall.

**Flavor wise, still NO**

The spell description says a lash of lightning, so this can be pictured as basically a whip made out of lightning. If you hit someone with a whip and pull them, and there is a pit between you and the pit, they are going to fall down that pit.

Comment: I think the question is if the pulling will successfully pull the target from one side of a pit to the other without the target falling in. It isnt clear that this answer rules on that particular scenario.

Comment: as soon as the person is no longer above solid ground, they fall unless they have a fly speed or levitation or some other way not to

Comment: So what happens if I hit you with *lightning lure* and you are below me? You go nowhere?

Comment: probably wouldn't move: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79025/62912

Comment: You could improve this answer by quoting rules that support the claims made (you've said "By RAW" but did not provide the rules). Also, that answer you linked isn't actually about moving up, it's about moving when something significant would prevent movement, and it doesn't specifically address whether gravity is a significant force for that. There is however [this related answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/168831) about pulling creatures into the air, that says such maneuvers *do* work

Comment: A pit is something that blocks movement though. Unless you have a way to fly or jump over it, you fall immediatly up to 500ft/round

Comment: A) pits *don't block movement* in the sense that you're implying. You can still move into/over a pits space with any movement you have (unlike say, a wall, which physically excludes you from entering its space) B) the 500ft/round is an optional rule from XGtE, not a core rule. Core, you fall the entire distance instantly.

Comment: fair, but that doesn't change the fact you fall that distance (500ft or all of it) instantly as soona s you are over that space. pull affects don't magically grant you a fly speed

Comment: It seems like you are saying that Crawford's tweet is "relevant rules", which is certainly not true.

Comment: its relevant in that crawford is clarifying that feather fall still works only because its an exception to the rule. Normally you fall isntantly

Comment: the basic falling rules just say you take damage, not whether it happens instantly or on your turn, so by RAW its GM interpretation, but most GMs go with isntantaneous. Yes the turns are supposed to be simultaneous, but even then if someone acts before you and knocks you out, you don't get to still do your attack on your turn, even if its the same turn. Falling is the same as being attacked in that regard, it happens instantly, the turn that you step off the cliff, whether its your turn or not. Xanathar's rule makes that RAW if you use the optionally falling as its worded "instantaneously"

Comment: If you get a chance, I suggest you review @nitsua60 homebrew for falling.  Best homebrew mod I've seen for this edition.

Comment: do you have a link? I searched and found his user but when I searched through his posts for "homebrew" I didn't find anything

Comment: @AndrewADeMarco Here we go, [finally found the link](https://homebrewery.naturalcrit.com/share/BJ79Xy491z).  I like the way it works and adds a cinematic feel to a battle near a precipice ... sorry it took me so long to get back to you.

Comment: its not bad. Right before your turn means you can use actions to save your friends. I would normally probably just have people make saves to not fall off (I already use that in my games), and have people that are adjacent have opportunity to use a reaction to catch them from falling. The have until their turn thing jsut feels weird to me, like the person is hanging in mid air like a cartoon and someone can take their turn to grab them before they fall even if they are 30ft away. That's a bit too generous IMO